# Javascript error in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I just downloaded iMacros and this is the first time i'm scripting in Javascript.I'm having a problem in iMacros. There is a site which has many branches and it goes like this

- site.com/1/1
- site.com/2/1
- site.com/3/1
- ...

What I want to do is view every branch of the site, till I reach 1000. So I wrote this

```
var x=1;
var macro;
macro+= "CODE:"
macro+= " URL GOTO=site.com/{{x}}/1" + "\n";
for (var i=1;i<10001;i++){
iimSet ("x",x);
iimPlay("macro");
x=x+1;
}
```

But i get an error which says: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"  nsresult: "0x80520001

So, what's causing this error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future, please don't mix up Java and Javascript. They are entirely different things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to open the .js file with Notepad and save it as UTF8 encoding.

And put x++; instead od x=x+1;